# What does the icc (or mpiicc) -E flag do?

Tags: fortran, icc, compiler-flags

I'm encountering a mystery flag in a build script.  It executes a command like

```
mpiicc -E driver.F90 > driver.tmp.f90
```

This places a few preprocessor directives at the top of driver.tmp.f90, but is otherwise identical to driver.F90.  In this case it looks like this:

```
# 1 "driver.F90"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1
# 1 "driver.F90" 2
```

I cannot find a description of the -E flag in the man entry or on Intel's website.  So what exactly is this flag doing?

Comment: For gcc at least -E just preprocess the file and then stops. Can you tell us the output of "mpicc --version" please?

Comment: For icc see e.g. https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt here it says: "-E                see Preprocessor Options" so I leave further investigation to you.

Comment: @IanBush That does seem to be the same function in icc.  The version I'm running is 18.0.3 20180410.

Comment: My icc 18.0.3 man page has an entry to `-E`. Does your version look "complete" or is it perhaps a minimal installation in some way? If it isn't the complete man page, then you can often get the same output that albert mentions with `icc --help`.

Comment: @fracescalus I feel rather silly now.  I just opened the man page for icc and I see it now.  I'm not sure how I missed that.  Apologies for the question.

Comment: Ah, I see now how it happened.  I was looking at the mpicc man page, which doesn't have it.  Still, I should have looked at icc's next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both Intel and Gnu C compilers the -E flag causes the compiler to run the C preprocessor on the file, and send the output to stdout. From the icc man page

```
  -E

          Causes the preprocessor to send output to stdout.

          Arguments:

          None

          Default:

          OFF               Preprocessed source files are output to
                            the compiler.

          Description:

          This option causes the preprocessor  to  send  output  to
          stdout.  Compilation  stops when the files have been pre-
          processed.

          When you specify this option, the compiler's preprocessor
          expands  your source module and writes the result to std-
          out. The preprocessed source contains  #line  directives,
          which  the compiler uses to determine the source file and
          line number.
```